# xamarin.forms (android ) Font scaling not working

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I want to have fix scaling regardless of user's settings. I am successful to get this working when user change the display settings and increase/decrease the font size.

But My app doesn't scale the fonts to 1 when:

- on app installation
- on font-family change

I have tried doing Font scaling through updating/overriding the configuration.

```
private void AdjustFontScale()
        {
            Configuration configuration = Resources.Configuration;
            var fontScale = configuration.FontScale;
            configuration.FontScale = (float)1;            
            DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();                       
            WindowManager.DefaultDisplay.GetMetrics(metrics);
            metrics.ScaledDensity = configuration.FontScale * metrics.Density;
           BaseContext.Resources.UpdateConfiguration(configuration, metrics);
        }

- I have added  android:configChanges="fontScale" in my androidmanifest.xml file.
- AdjustFontScale() is called from OnCreate(), OnResume() and from OnConfigurationChanged() functions.
```

I expect fonts should be scaled to 1 at App installation.

Answer (score 0):

you could try to override **attachBaseContext** method:

```
protected override void AttachBaseContext(Context @base)
{
    Configuration overrideConfiguration = new Configuration();
    overrideConfiguration = @base.Resources.Configuration;
    overrideConfiguration.SetToDefaults();
    var fontScale = overrideConfiguration.FontScale;
    overrideConfiguration.FontScale = (float)1;                   
    Context context = @base.CreateConfigurationContext(overrideConfiguration);
    base.AttachBaseContext(context);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Cause UpdateConfiguration is deprecated you should use this variant now. Min and Max font size supported. Xamarin.Essential is needed to access display density.

```
        public void AdjustFontScale()
    {
        var minFontScale = 0.9f;
        var maxFontScale = 1.3f;
        Configuration configuration = Resources.Configuration;
        configuration.FontScale = Math.Max(minFontScale, Math.Min(maxFontScale, configuration.FontScale));
        ApplicationContext.Resources.Configuration.UpdateFrom(configuration);
        BaseContext.Resources.Configuration.UpdateFrom(configuration);
        BaseContext.Resources.DisplayMetrics.ScaledDensity = configuration.FontScale * (float)DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Density;
    }
```